# Can you test if the feature of a dependency is set using the `cfg!` macro?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to test if a feature of one of my dependencies has been set using the `cfg!` macro.

Below is an example:

my-lib/Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "my-lib"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[features]
some-feature = []
```

my-lib/lib.rs

```rust
pub fn some_function() {
    if cfg!(feature = "some-feature") {
        println!("SET");
    } else {
        println!("NOT SET");
    }
}
```

my-bin/Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "my-bin"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
my-lib = { path = "../my-lib" }
```

my-bin/main.rs

```rust
use my_lib;

fn main() {
    my_lib::some_function();

    if cfg!(feature = "my-lib/some-feature") {
        println!("is SET in bin");
    } else {
        println!("is NOT SET in bin");
    }
}
```

Below shows the output given different run conditions. I would expect the second scenario to show `is SET in bin`.

```
> cargo run --features ""
NOT SET
is NOT SET in bin
```

```
> cargo run --features "my-lib/some-feature"
SET
is NOT SET in bin
```

A workaround is to add `bin-some-feature = ["my-lib/some-feature"]` to "my-bin/Cargo.toml" and change the check in "my-bin/main.rs" to `cfg!(feature = "bin-some-feature")`. This produces the desired output.

```
> cargo run --features "bin-some-feature"
SET
is SET in bin
```

Comment: No, cargo doesn't pass it directly. But you're the one controlling the presence of a dependency, aren't you?

Comment: It's not optimal, I wouldn't call it _a workaround_, it's the recommended approach for now. I'd also remove the `bin-` prefix and use just `some-feature = ["my-lib/some-feature"]`.

Comment: The workaround works only as long as you're the only one possibly using that feature. If you depend on `another-lib` which depends on `my-lib`,  then `another-lib` can turn on the `my-lib/some-feature` feature and your bin will never know. So it's fine as long as you care only about your own features, but checking if some `serde` feature is set in a large project cannot be done like this. But you can use e.g. `cargo tree`.